# Partially hide email address with RegEx and Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to using RegEx to hide email addresses, except for the first two characters and the email domain.

The function, in that case, is replacing the characters that I want to keep.

```
email.replace(/^[A-Za-z]{2}/, "**" ).replace(/@[^:]*/, "**" )
```

What I get: `email@domain.com > **ail**`
Expected: `em***@domain.com`

Anyone here who knows how can I change my RegEx to get the expected result?

Thanks!

Comment: This is the best I could get: `"abcdef@gmail.com".replace(/(.{2})(.*)(?=@)/, '$1*')`.

Comment: Why are you doing this with JavaScript? The email addresses are actually already in the client's browser. So, this is only for display purposes. It's not safe to use it to actually prevent the user to see the email addresses.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I could only achieve that with a function in the `replace`. Not sure if that can be achieved with only regex tho. Check it out:

```js
let hideEmail = function(email) {
  return email.replace(/(.{2})(.*)(?=@)/,
    function(gp1, gp2, gp3) { 
      for(let i = 0; i < gp3.length; i++) { 
        gp2+= "*"; 
      } return gp2; 
    });
};

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
  let emailField = document.querySelector("input");
      
  console.log(hideEmail(emailField.value));
});
```

```html
<input type="email" value="abcdef@gmail.com">
<button>Hide e-mail</button>
```

Answer (score 14):

This worked perfectly for me:

```js
const email = "username@domain.tld"
const partialEmail = email.replace(/(\w{3})[\w.-]+@([\w.]+\w)/, "$1***@$2")
console.log(partialEmail)
```

It captures first 3 characters (just replace the number as per your needs) in 1st group and the domain in 2nd.

Answer (score 3):

You could try this, show first two characters and the rest always `***` in the user part:

```js
var email = "exampleexample@example.com";

let hide = email.split("@")[0].length - 2;//<-- number of characters to hide

var r = new RegExp(".{"+hide+"}@", "g")

email = email.replace(r, "***@" );

console.log(email)
```

I don't know if the three `*` is a requirement, but I think is a good idea, because you hide the real length.

Comment: OP wants to keep only two characters at the beggining, and not to hide the last three..

Answer (score 3):

You can also have this,`(?<=^[A-Za-z0-9]{2}).*?(?=@)`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/1DFxRe/1)

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution in flutter of dart

```
"example@gmail.com".replaceRange(
                                  0,
                                  "example@gmail.com"
                                          .indexOf("@") -
                                      3,
                                  "****")
```

It will show result like that-
*******ple@gmail.com***